# Python - rolling a dice fairly and counting how many 4's I get

Tags: python, dice

So I had to make code that roll a die fairly and counted how many 4's I got. With the help of you all on here I got it to work. Well now I have to created another die and roll them and then add they products together. This is the instructions I've been given.

> "Then write another function that simulates rolling two fair dice. The
>   easy way is to call the function you just wrote, twice, and add the
>   numbers you get. This should return a number between 2 and 12. It
>   should calculate BOTH numbers in ONE run – you are counting two
>   distinct things."

And this is my code freshly fixed.

```
from random import randrange
def roll():
    rolled = randrange(1,7)
    if rolled == 1:
        return "1"
    if rolled == 2:
        return "2"
    if rolled == 3:
        return "3"
    if rolled == 4:
        return "4"
    if rolled == 5:
        return "5"
    if rolled == 6:
        return "6"


def rollManyCountTwo(n):
    twoCount = 0
    for i in range (n):
        if roll() == "2":
            twoCount += 1
    print ("In", n,"rolls of a pair of dice, there were",twoCount,"twos.")

rollManyCountTwo(6000)
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong, you're rolling a dice six times and return "1" if the first roll is a 1, "2" if the first one wasn't one and the second one is 2, etc. (Every new call to `randrange` gives you a new random number.)

Comment: Surely a fair dice roll would get *only* fours: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: What is your question? You've just copy-pasted your homework instructions here. Do you really just want your homework code to be reviewed here?

Comment: no my question is that I have to make another dice and then add the results of the 2 dice together and I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `randrange()` inside the `roll()` in every `if` condition, instead you should call it once and save it in a variable and check.

The code would look like -

```
from random import randrange
def roll():
    rolled = randrange(1,7)
    if rolled == 1:
        return "1"
    if rolled == 2:
        return "2"
    if rolled == 3:
        return "3"
    if rolled == 4:
        return "4"
    if rolled == 5:
        return "5"
    if rolled == 6:
        return "6"


def rollManyCountFour(n):
    fourCount = 0
    for i in range (n):
        if roll() == "6":
            fourCount += 1
    print ("In", n,"rolls of a due, there were",fourCount,"fours.")

rollManyCountFour(6000)
```

Comment: randrange() is inclusive so `randrange(1,7)` is wrong

Comment: This worked for me, except I have to use randrange(1,7) because otherwise it says I get roll 0 when I ask for 6's. But this worked otherwise!

Comment: @Ash yeah sorry my bad randrange(1,7) will work because upper bound is not inclusive .. got confused :)

Comment: that's okay! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is bad, and hence, not as random as it should be.

`randrange(low,up)` includes both boundaries.

Look at what you do in the `roll` function:

you roll a dice. If it is `1`, you return `"1"`. 
If it is not `1`, you *roll the dice again*! That's simply wrong, and in a game would be considered cheating.

Your roll function is absolutely unnecessary, and can be replaced by 
`str(randrange(1,6))`.

Also, why would you need the numbers as strings? You don't actually use these strings, so just stick with the result of `randrange` as it is -- a number.

**EDIT**:

You say

> Yeah I'm assuming some of it is unnecessary but it's for a class and this is the way he wants it so I'm trying to keep it how he wants. I thought that's what I was doing but I could find a way around it!

All of it is unnecessary. There is a function that does what you want, so no need to encapsulate this in a class.

Well, you can just

```
class ash_class(object):
    def roll():
        return str(randrange(1,6))
```

For your counting problem: Python comes with all the tools.

```
counts = [0] * 6 # this is [0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(n):
    counts[randrange(1,6)] += 1
print counts
```

As you notice, it's really handy if the randrange numbers are *numbers* and not strings, as you can then use them like *numbers* to index an array.

As a personal advice: There should always be the freedom to discuss bad design choice. One such bad design choice is forcing you to convert numbers to strings, when you clearly need to work with them as numbers.

Comment: Yeah I'm assuming some of it is unnecessary but it's for a class and this is the way he wants it so I'm trying to keep it how he wants. I thought that's what I was doing but I could find a way around it!

Comment: Yeah I assumed there's easier simpler ways to do this. and yes you can say it's bad, sorry if I came off over bearing? I was just letting you know that while what you said is easier, smarter, better, I'm unable to use it. That way you didn't think I was just blowing off your response which I appreciate.

Comment: @Ash: I took absolutely no offense in anything you've said. The comment I made about discussing bad design choices was more to encourage you to talk to whoever tasked you with the assignment to write a function that returns a string with some self-confidence!

Comment: Well good! Thank you! I understand that seeing code like this can aggravate those of you who are exceptional at programming. I have 0 knowledge in this and am learning it all online so I'm grateful for everyone on here!

Comment: @Ash, I'm really not aggravated in any way. I just think it's a bad choice that you need to convert numbers to strings, and I want to make you feel confident about your self, so that you can discuss this with who gave you that task :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used `np.random.randint(1, 7, N)`, with N being the number of rolls and have used the following system to store it (if this helps):

```
R1s = 0
R2s = 0
R3s = 0
R4s = 0
R5s = 0
R6s = 0
for i in range(0, N):
    if x[i] == 1:
        R1s += 1
    elif x[i] == 2:
        R2s += 1
    elif x[i] == 3:
        R3s += 1
    elif x[i] == 4:
        R4s += 1
    elif x[i] == 5:
        R5s += 1
    else:
        R6s += 1

print(R1s)
# Ans ≈ N/6
```