# Python - creating 2 dice to roll fairly and add them together?

Tags: python, dice

So I had to make code that roll a die fairly and counted how many 4's I got. With the help of people on here I got it to work. Well now I have to created another die and roll them and then add they products together. This is the instructions I've been given.

"Then write another function that simulates rolling two fair dice. The easy way is to call the function you just wrote, twice, and add the numbers you get.
This should return a number between 2 and 12."

I've added rolling the dice a second time but how do I add the sums of the two rolls together is my question?
And this is my code.

```
from random import randrange
def roll():
    rolled = randrange(1,7)
    if rolled == 1:
        return "1"
    if rolled == 2:
        return "2"
    if rolled == 3:
        return "3"
    if rolled == 4:
        return "4"
    if rolled == 5:
        return "5"
    if rolled == 6:
        return "6"

def rollManyCountTwo(n):
    twoCount = 0
    for i in range (n):
        if roll() == "2":
            twoCount += 1
        if roll() == "2":
            twoCount +=1
    print ("In", n,"rolls of a pair of dice, there were",twoCount,"twos.")

rollManyCountTwo(6000)
```

Comment: Why are you returning strings and not integers?

Comment: Please learn how to format code. This is the third time the huge number of `<br>`s get removed from your questions. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30934834/2301450), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932635/python-rolling-a-dice-fairly-and-counting-how-many-4s-i-get)

Comment: That's how my teacher is having us do it. I hate it. and sorry I don't know how to format stuff on here.

Comment: If you must return strings then you still don't need all those `if`s, you can just use `str()` to convert the result to a string, regardless of what number it is.

Comment: @Ash [these buttons](http://imgur.com/QkidvuI) were put there exactly to simplify formatting. There's also a big question mark on the right, click it to get help.

Comment: I looked through all that and still didn't understand. So I went to google and tried to find things and so that's why there were <br> everywhere it was the only way I knew to space it to the next line so it could be a tiny bit legible. Next time I'll spend more time looking at it.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have to deal with strings at all, this could be done entirely using `int` values

```
from random import randint

def roll():
    return randint(1,6)

def roll_twice():
    total = 0
    for turn in range(2):
        total += roll()
    return total
```

For example

```
>>> roll_twice()
10
>>> roll_twice()
7
>>> roll_twice()
8
```

And for your function that is supposed to count the number of `2`s that were rolled, again you can do integer comparison

```
def rollManyCountTwo(n):
    twos = 0
    for turn in range(n):
        if roll() == 2:
            twos += 1
    print('In {} rolls of a pair of dice there were {} twos'.format(n, twos))
    return twos

>>> rollManyCountTwo(600)
In 600 rolls of a pair of dice there were 85 twos
85
```

Comment: Also, using `randint(1,6)` seems more suitable here, instead of `randrange(1,7)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

def roll():
    return randint(1,6)

def rollManyCountTwo(n):
    twoCount = 0
    for _n in xrange(n*2):
        if roll() == 2:
            twoCount += 1
    print "In {n} rolls of a pair of dice, there were {cnt} twos.".format(n=n, cnt=twoCount)
```

Since you roll two dices for `n` times and count every single two rolled, just loop for `n*2` and check if the dice result is two.